# How to read tbf file with STAMP encryption

Tags: c#, python, sql, database, sml

I have Toronto Stock Exchange stock data in a maxtor hard drive. The data is a TBF file with `.dat` and `.pos` components. The `.dat` file contains all the Stamp format transmission information in binary format.

I can read `.pos` file using R. It has 3 column with numbers, which make no sense to me. The data is information on stock and I think it is the result of Streambase.

I need to get 2007 price, value, and etc. information on some stocks that I am interested in.
Could you please suggest any way to read the data? Should I use some particular software to make sense of this data?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in using something like FileViewerPro? Its free download tool in order to open files. Also, what windows programs have you tried so far, like notepad, excel?